Integrating AWS Cognito and Azure AD: Allowing access for any Microsoft User even if they are not in the Azure AD?
Okay so my goal was to integrate google and microsoft with aws cognito to give allow users to signup/signin using their google and microsoft accounts. The google one works perfectly but since there was no Microsoft integration in aws natively I followed various tutorials.
I ended up creating a OpenID Connect (OIDC) identity provider in the cognito pool and in Azure portal i created a directory from which i mapped the following to the OIDC i created:
Application (client) ID
Client Secret
Issuer URL:**
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0**
and scopes of
**openid profile email
and set attribute request method as post
**
In my react application i am using:
await Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'Microsoft' });

and my redirect url in the auth in azure is
https://{{my cognito pool domain}}/oauth2/idpresponse
now this works perfectly for a user that exists in azure AD and it allows the entire flow to completes creates a user in cognito with external provider but it doesn't work for any other microsoft email except for the ones that are users in azure AD and i get the error
AADSTS50020: User account '{{email}}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant '{{Azure app name}}' and cannot access the application '{{application id}} in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
I want to create something that allows every Microsoft user even if they don't exist in AD to signup using microsoft and use my react app
What can i do and what am i doing wrong? Can anyone please help me on this?

To resolve the error, create Azure AD application by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" and pass URL as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common instead of TenantID

Let me know if this works for your I will post an answer

Or in Azure AD app manisfest change signInAudience as AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount

@Rukmini thank you for responding. I appreciate the help.
so in Supported account types the option "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)" is already selected.
For the other app manifest setting i get an error "Failed to update QAtest application. Error detail: Property accessTokenAcceptedVersion is invalid. [P49I+Qvrtu0+GABQVMcpKd]" when i try to change the signinAudience.
Can you guide me?

Yeah you have to also set accessTokenAcceptedVersion as 2 in the Azure ad manifest

okay let me try this and get back to you.

@Rukmini so I tried these changes and first i tried an account that doesn't exist as a user in my AD to check that gave me an error Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS500200: User account 'myemail@hotmail.com' is a personal Microsoft account. Personal Microsoft accounts are not supported for this application unless explicitly invited to an organization. Try signing out and signing back in with an organizational account.

Then i tried an email that existed in AD and was previously working with my app that returned to my app home but got redirected i used localhost to check the return url "http://localhost:3000/ #error_description=Bad+id_token+issuer+https%3A%2F%2Fsts.windows.net%2Ff38c559b-4c9a-4d89-9bb2-75ae97a3d889&state=41f6uAuEQOql2u5UWVatAJpIUps8QjNt&error=invalid_request"
Any ideas what it could be?

Did you pass common in the sign in url instead of tenant id?

in the Issuer URL of OIDC in cognito i changed it to: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
Do i need to change the OAuth 2.0 grant types in the cognito app too?

@Rukmini for additional context my aws react setup looks like
Amplify.configure({
Auth: {
...
oauth: {
domain: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN,
scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
redirectSignIn: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_SIGNIN,
redirectSignOut: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_SIGNOUT,
responseType: 'token',
},},}

What is the sign in url you are using

@Rukmini i am using my react app site for sign and signout urls in react aswell as the cognito app

What is the Microsoft URL are you using?

Issuer
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
tried
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0 aswell
And the cognito domain is my cognito domain url
the redirect uri in azure authentication is https://cognitodomain/oauth2/idpresponse

Can you try this to authorize users https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

so i tried updating this in my issuer url it gives an error that says
[InvalidParameterException] Failed to update identity provider Microsoft
requestId: 5378973e-55ad-45a1-80af-364127f2c106
time: Wed Jul 24 2024 16:13:27 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
code: InvalidParameterException
message: Unable to contact well-known endpoint

Issuer URL must be https://sts.windows.net/common

sorry so I did this and it went through the login flow and then redirected back to my app with url /#error_description=Bad+id_token+issuer+https%3A%2F%2Fsts.windows.net%2Ff38c559b-4c9a-4d89-9bb2-75ae97a3d889&state=yfXYxxz1PGkJO25gt9Ulhg43yG9B9Ser&error=invalid_request

Are you able to sign in with any Microsoft account?

no, i could sign in with my account that existed in the azure AD with the issuer url with tenant id but with the new url i cannot

I am not sure about the AWS config, in Azure AD side you to allow all the Microsoft users you need to replace TenantID by common and configure app as n by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0
Tried replacing the issuer url again with the this one and it worked,
what do you think could be the issue here

I googled and read a few old forums that said it isn't supported but i thought maybe you might know better.  But thanks for all the help really appreciate it. Do let me know if you can think of what this issue might be

I didn't understand your last comment.
and sure You can post the answer

Posting an answer with all details

Can you try setting issuer as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0

tried this and got "/#error_description=Bad+id_token+issuer+https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2F9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad%2Fv2.0&state=f2Y1qdUypOBCcM2dw6CmeFWhNxltrGrC&error=invalid_request"

Okay then go with what you have set previously and please check the answer below


AADSTS50020: User account '{{email}}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant '{{Azure app name}}' and cannot access the application '{{application id}} in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

The error usually occurs if the Microsoft Entra ID application is not configured as Multitenant with option "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" and if the sign-in URL is not set as common.

Hence to resolve the error, make sure to register the Azure AD application like below:


And in the Manifest update the accessTokenAcceptedVersion as 2.
Based on this MsDoc, the issuer URL must be set as <authentication-endpoint>/<tenant-id>/v2.0 that is the authentication-endpoint must be https://login.microsoftonline.com for V2.0 endpoints.
For the applications which supports Multitenant and Microsoft personal accounts the issuer must be set as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
Reference:
Azure Functions with multi tenant authentication - Coding Stephan (svrooij.io) by Stephan

Any update on the issue?
